# npm downloads package in multiple versions

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-modules

In my package.json I've added a package and another package which is a dependency of the first package. The dependency tree looks like this:

```
@
|
+---+ A@0.0.1
|   |
|   +---+ B@^0.0.1
|
+--- B@0.0.2
```

As the package A requires B in version ^0.0.1 (with a caret) and the project also requires package B in version 0.0.2 (directly in package.json), after invoking `npm install` I would expect the tree would be flattened to the following  form:

```
@
|
+--- A@0.0.1
|
+--- B@0.0.2
```

Yet it is not. After installing packages, the npm creates a folder in node_modules for module A in version 0.0.2, creates a folder in node_modules for module B in version 0.0.1 and under the folder B it creates another node_modules with A in version 0.0.1 (despite a caret in the required version). So my question is: why? Am I missing something? Do I understand the purpose of carets and tildes incorrectly? How can I force npm to flatten this strucure? `npm dedupe` did not help.

Comment: Which result do you expect?

Comment: to fetch higher version of b. its stated in the question

Comment: @Szab will ~ insteed of ^ change the behavior?

Comment: @Antoniossss I will be able to check it tomorrow (don't have access to needed repositories right now) - I'll let you know. However: doesn't ^ (a caret) match everything that ~ (a tilde) matches + minor versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is right, but caret treats a major version of `0` differently: It only allows updates in patches and for `0.0.x` it doesn't allow updates at all.

For example, `^0.0.3` will only permit exactly version `0.0.3`.

For versions greater than or equal to 0.1.0, but less than 1.0.0, the caret adopts the same behavior as a tilde and will allow flexibility in patch versions (only).

For example, `^0.1.3` will permit all versions from `0.1.3` to the next minor, `0.2.0`.

The reason behind that is that before the first `1.0.0` release, a different patch or minor number does not guarantee that changes are non-breaking.

[source](https://github.com/npm/node-semver/pull/41)